# Creating a database for Dictionary app

Tags: java, android

I'm starting to learn to develop an android app. I would like to develop a native language dictionary in android. My question is how to create a database that can store the vocabulary (text), audio (pronunciation) as well as picture? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

To avoid memory Problem you can store your Audio and Image file in SD card and just save the Name of the files in your database. When you need those file just take the details from the DB and play/Show from SD Card. This is the best approach as my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,Krishnakant Dahal ... !!! Do you have any suggestion link for me reference how to learn about sqlite databese?

Comment: Its Dalal. Anyway heres the Link http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html

Answer (score 2):

Normal SQLite Database is enough for your App to store such things like audio, picture, etc,.
Be clear that if you are going to create native app it's better to use your SD card for storing images and audio files, from this you can able to retrieve the files based on your needs.

Comment: How can I retrieve those audio files and images? Can you provide the coding? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

SQLite will be a reasonable solution.

If you need to connect to a network DB, I suggest a PHP script on the server where the MySQL db is hosted.

Here's some sample code for what an SQLite db looks like:

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // All Static variables
    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "android_api";

    // Login table name
    private static final String TABLE_LOGIN = "login";

    // Login Table Columns names
    private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    private static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    private static final String KEY_UID = "uid";
    private static final String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LOGIN + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,"
                + KEY_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_EMAIL + " TEXT UNIQUE,"
                + KEY_UID + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_CREATED_AT + " TEXT" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_LOGIN_TABLE);
    }

    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LOGIN);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Storing user details in database
     * */
    public void addUser(String name, String email, String uid, String created_at) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, name); // Name
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email
        values.put(KEY_UID, uid); // Email
        values.put(KEY_CREATED_AT, created_at); // Created At

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void addUser(String email) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email); // Email

        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LOGIN, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public String getUser() {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

        String user = values.getAsString(KEY_EMAIL);
        Log.v("DBH", user);
        db.close();
        return user;        
    }

    /**
     * Getting user data from database
     * */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails(){
        HashMap<String,String> user = new HashMap<String,String>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
        // Move to first row
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            user.put("name", cursor.getString(1));
            user.put("email", cursor.getString(2));
            user.put("uid", cursor.getString(3));
            user.put("created_at", cursor.getString(4));
        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Getting user login status
     * return true if rows are there in table
     * */
    public int getRowCount() {
        String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
        int rowCount = cursor.getCount();
        db.close();
        cursor.close();

        // return row count
        return rowCount;
    }

    public String returnRows() {
        String response = "";
        String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_LOGIN;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        for (int j = 0; j < getRowCount(); j++) {
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            response += cursor.getColumnName(j);
        }
        Log.v("LT", response);
        return response;
    }

    /**
     * Re crate database
     * Delete all tables and create them again
     * */
    public void resetTables(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        // Delete All Rows
        db.delete(TABLE_LOGIN, null, null);
        db.close();
    }
```

Comment: I'm developing an offline dictionary. Can it still apply? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, look at addUser. SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);